# Spring MVC (Can't Instantiate my Object in correct sequence)

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc, servlet-3.0

I want to get an instance of ServletContext right after my project initialization and before any other controller class load into memory then after that I want to use ServletContext Features like:

```
getRealPath();
```

This is because I want to parse an important file which does load RMI Info (RMI HOST, RMI Port)

What is your solution ? ( Remember I need This object to be created once only and that should be before my Controller Classes Instaniation & then I want to get reference to that object everywhere in my project inside my Controller class methods)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [ServletContextListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html). It's invoked when the application is started, and when it's destroyed.

Comment: Can you please explain how I'm gonna get it ?

Comment: How you're gonna get what?

Comment: what I mean is how to solve this problem & get it to work 
can you please read the post below ?

Comment: Click the edit link at the bottom of your question. Show us the code of your listener. Show us how you configured it using annotations or the web.xml.